# shell script runs by crontab but no output

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have the following script:

```
serverName # more alarmsScript.sh 
#!/bin/bash
now=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")
before=$(date -d '1 hour ago' +"%Y%m%d%H%M")
/opt/SMAW/INTP/bin/AdvErrLogViewer.pl -s `echo $before` -e `echo $now` -m 'all' '/advdata/trace/AdvErrorTrace/CCC_USER_*' | grep -B 2 -A 2 -i major >/dump/stats/IN-$now.txt
```

when i run it `./alarmsScript.sh` it runs fine the output file `IN-xxxx.txt` is getting generated with the required data.

BUT when runs by crontab the output file is empty

```
15 * * * * /dump/scripts/alarmsScript.sh
```

example of the generated output file:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 adv adv   0 Sep  4 20:15 IN-201609042015.txt
```

Comment: Is it possible that `AdvErrLogViewer.pl` uses some session variables such as $LOGNAME, $HOME, $LANG or something like this?
1) Try to remove `grep` and check output file
2) Try to replace call of `AdvErrLogViewer.pl` with `echo $before $now` and check output file.

Also you may replace `\`echo $var\`` with simply `"$var"` -- it is the same.

Comment: i would recommend to rewrite cron job like this: "15 * * * * /dump/scripts/alarmsScript.sh 2>&1 > /tmp/crontab.log" to see if any errors there

Comment: @sr3z B etter `15 * * * * /dump/scripts/alarmsScript.sh > /tmp/crontab.log 2>&1"` to stderr comes in crontab.log too.

Comment: Dies `AdvErrLogViewer`.pl` need something set in your `.bashrc` file (PATH, libs, ..) ?

Comment: @Walter A i have got ````unable to read CEs via AdvDbTool -p all````

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the pipe is the problem?
Try to put the results to the file in two steps.
Frist output the result to a temp file.
Then grep the temp file and output the results to destination.

> /opt/SMAW/INTP/bin/AdvErrLogViewer.pl -s `echo $before` -e `echo $now` -m 'all' '/advdata/trace/AdvErrorTrace/CCC_USER_*' > /tmp/middleFile.tmp
>
> grep -B 2 -A 2 -i major /tmp/middleFile.tmp  > /dump/stats/IN-$now.txt